# Add/remove pipeline checks using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a requirement to dynamically add/remove or enable disable approval and checks at azure DevOps pipeline environment.
Is there a rest api for this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a rest api for this?

Yes, it has. BUT, as what the @Krysztof said, we haven't provide such api documents to public as of today. This is because what you are looking for is one feature *(configure `Check and approval` from `environments` )* that only support for YAML pipeline, and until now, we are developing but does not publish the corresponding rest api *(for YAML)* docs.

But, as work around, you can catch these apis from **F12**. Just do action from UI, then capture and analyze corresponds api records to found out what you are expecting.

Here I make the summary to you.

The api that used to add/delete approval and check to environment is:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations
```

The corresponding **api method** for `add or delete` is `Post` and `DELETE`.

---

Firstly, share you the request body samples which for `approval and check` **added**.

**1)** Add **approval** to this environment:

```
{
  "type": {
    "id": "8C6F20A7-A545-4486-9777-F762FAFE0D4D", // The fixed value for Approval 
    "name": "Approval"
  },
  "settings": {
    "approvers": [
      {
        "id": "f3c88b9a-b49f-4126-a4fe-3c99ecbf6303" // User Id 
      }
    ],
    "executionOrder": 1, 
    "instructions": "",
    "blockedApprovers": [],
    "minRequiredApprovers": 0,  
    "requesterCannotBeApprover": false // The pipeline requester allow to approve it.
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "environment",
    "id": "1",           // Environment id
    "name": "Deployment" //Environment name
  },
  "timeout": 43200 // Set the available time(30d) of this approval pending. The measure unit is seconds.
}
```

**2)** Add **task check**, `Azure function`, `Invoke rest api` task and etc:

```
{
  "type": {
    "id": "fe1de3ee-a436-41b4-bb20-f6eb4cb879a7", // Fixed value if you want to add task check
    "name": "Task Check" //Fixed value
  },
  "settings": {
    "definitionRef": {
      "id": "537fdb7a-a601-4537-aa70-92645a2b5ce4", //task Id 
      "name": "AzureFunction", //task name
      "version": "1.0.10" //task version
    },
    "displayName": "Invoke Azure Function", //task display name configured
    "inputs": {
      "method": "POST",  
      "waitForCompletion": "false",
      "function": "csdgsdgsa",
      "key": "436467543756"  // These are all task inputs
    },
    "retryInterval": 5, // The re-try time specified.
    "linkedVariableGroup": "AzKeyGroup"// The variable group name this task linked with
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "environment",
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Development"
  },
  "timeout": 43200
}
```

In this request body, you can find the corresponding `task id` from our [public source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks). Just check the [`task.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFunctionV1/task.json#L2) file of corresponding task.

**3)** Add **template check**:

```
{
  "type": {
    "id": "4020E66E-B0F3-47E1-BC88-48F3CC59B5F3", // Fixed value for template check added.
    "name": "ExtendsCheck" //Fixed value
  },
  "settings": {
    "extendsChecks": [
      {
        "repositoryType": "git", // github for Github source, bitbucket for Bitbucket source
        "repositoryName": "MonnoPro", 
        "repositoryRef": "refs/heads/master",
        "templatePath": "tem.yml"
      }
    ]
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "environment",
    "id": "6",
    "name": "development"
  }
}
```

In this body, if the template source is coming from **github** or **bitbucket**, the value of repositoryName should like `{org name}/{repos name}`.

Hope these are helps.

Comment: This works well for adding approval to an environment. However, I cannot seem to find the ability to LIST all approvals/checks for a given environment ID (so I can programmatically tell if an approval exists on an environment already)? Any ideas?

Comment: @Travis, did you find any reliable solution regarding listing the approvals/checks?

Comment: I found out you can determine the existing checks for an environment using this endpoint: GET https://dev.azure.com/[OrgName]/[ProjectName]/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations/?resourceType=environment&resourceId=[EnvironmentId]&api-version=6.0-preview.1

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question but we had a similar need. There does not appear to be a direct API To query this, but this [GitHub Project](https://github.com/JtMotoX/azure-devops-api/blob/6f22daa3bbca974ea4c82864f8d27ccdf6f82982/environments.http#L74) pointed us in the right direction:

```js
# GET ENVIRONMENT CHECKS (stored under .fps.dataProviders.data['ms.vss-pipelinechecks.checks-data-provider'].checkConfigurationDataList)
GET https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_environments/{{environment_id}}/checks?__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

As mentioned above under `.fps.dataProviders.data['ms.vss-pipelinechecks.checks-data-provider'].checkConfigurationDataList` the list of who is authorized is provided.

The officially [documented APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/check-configurations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) can tell you that there are checks in place; for example:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations?resourceType=environment&resourceId={id}
```

Can tell you that you have checks enabled (including an `Approval` check) but this isn't super useful as it does not give a list of who can Approve.

Note that you can get the list of environments (to get their resource ID) using this [documented API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported at the moment. You can upvote feature request to show your interest [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/859033/rest-api-to-manage-environments-yaml-pipelines.html).